# Unsubscribe users in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm redesigning a website in symfony2, where users must be able to unsubscribe.

When they do, for database integrity reasons, we have to de-activate their account, and not completely delete it. We must also keep track of their personnal information, like email adress, for a certain time (legal obligation).

I'm using FOSUserBundle, and I initially thought a simple way to deactivate accounts of people who unsubscribed, would be to set the User property "enabled" to false.

But when a user is not enabled, if he tries to register again with the same email adress, he sees : "The email is already used". And I would like he could register again and create a new account (or reactivate the old one).

Is there a way to do this ? 
Is there a best practice to handle unsubscriptions with FOSUserBundle ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the main registration process with, the `easyextendbundle`, you could have a look at the documentation at this url:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html

Then in your extended controller, you have to create a new action to activate or deactivate your user, this action must be public in the security rules.

In this method, you could use the services to activate or deactivate a user:

`fos:user:deactivate` Deactivate a user
`fos:user:activate` Activate a user

You could inspire yourself from this earlier post : [Symfony2: List Users with Option to Deactivate Each User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787647/symfony2-list-users-with-option-to-deactivate-each-user)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not my question, I know how to deactivate users, this is what I do already : I created a unsuscribe action in the front end, which deactivate (enabled = false) the user. 
My concern is more that a deactivated user is not really like an unsubscribed user ; mainly, he can't register again later. 
So my question is : can you authorize a deactivated user to register again, and how ? Do you have to rewrite the whole registration logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to update your User class with the property `$subscribed` as below:

```
/**
 *  @ORM\Column(name="subscribed", type="boolean")
 */
protected $subscribed;

public function setSubscribed($subscribed)
{
    $this->subscribed = $subscribed;
}

public function isSubscribed($)
{
    return $this->subscribed;
}

public function changeSubscribed()
{
    $this->subscribed = !$this->subscribed;
}
```

This avoids e-mail address conflicts without adding another third-party bundle.

Edit (note also set method above)

in YourBundle\EventListener

```
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Persist organization on staff registration success.
     *
     * @param \FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var $user \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface */
        $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
        $user->setSubscribed(true);
    }
}
```

also, add to app/config/services.yml:

```
your_bundle.regisration.listener:
    class: YourBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you link this new property with user permissions like connect, register, etc... Do you rewrite FOSUserBundle controllers ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "connect". For register you can add a registration listener so the user is subscribed when registration is successful.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: The `isSubscribed()` method was mistakenly deleted and is now restored.